# Umbraco - Vorto value

Tags: c#, umbraco

I'm trying to get a Vorto Value in a custom class. First I include this:

```
using Our.Umbraco.Vorto.Extensions;
```

And then my code :

```
var umbracoHelper = new Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper(Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext.Current);
var node = umbracoHelper.TypedContent(nodeId);
var texte = node.GetVortoValue("texte", "en-US").ToString();
```

I got an error in the `using` telling me `Our` could not be found.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you add the reference to the Vorto's dll?

Comment: What's the dll ?

Comment: our.umbraco.vorto.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a late answer. It's very likely, if you installed the package through Umbraco Package Manager and not through NuGet, the @using might not work in class files, but only in views.

Therefore, you have to also install the package through NuGet, that should make the @using valid in the class files.

```
Install-Package Our.Umbraco.Vorto
```

You can also manually reference the .DLL through References.

Comment: Lucky I saw this randomly searching around. Thanks, haha.